# How to use sudoers and regular expressions with grep

Tags: linux, grep, sudo

I am trying to do grep on all log files which are under directory `/var/log/application/archived/`

And I have  sudo access. Trying like below is giving me error

```
sudo grep 'checkThis' /var/log/application/archived/*.log
```

Error

```
grep: /var/log/application/archived/*.log: No such file or directory
```

I tried with escape char but doesn't seems to work

and If I give any one file name instead of * it gives me result.

Eg : `sudo grep 'checkThis' /var/log/application/archived/firstLogFile.log`   this gives me expected response

Comment: Why can't you recursively grep the `archived` directory?

Comment: Can you even `cd` to that directory? http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171316/148686

Comment: No I can't do cd to that directory. It says `sudo: cd: command not found`

Comment: You don't need sudo for every single command

Comment: The message clearly states that some part of that path does not exist: either the folder itself  or it does not contain any .log files. Sudo access is not magic. What does running ls on your folder result in?

Comment: If you just run `sudo -i` you'll become the root user, so you can freely run all your commands

Comment: cd might be a problem because it's a shell builtin in most cases.

Comment: @ cricket_007 For cd when I tried without sudo - it shows 'access denied' which is obvious!! and I should not be doing sudo -i as it is restricted environment!! Hence my question.

Comment: @ Mad Physicist Thanks for your comment!  Well, files do exists and the path is correct as well, When I checked with some one who as root access  - is able to run same command without sudo!

Comment: @MadPhysicist @ cricket_007  thanks for your suggestions/comments.. command provided in the answer below worked for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use below command to do grep of all log files with sudo access

sudo sh -c "grep 'stringToSearch' /var/log/archived/*.log"